# Jquery validate form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate my form on submit and if the input's are all filled in they submit to register.php

My problem being it only works if all inputs are blank - otherwise it errors - I'm just trying to check if any of those fields are blank before submiting

```
function submitform() {
    if ($('#name, #email, #user, #address, #phone').val().length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass('warning');
    } else {
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `==` instead of `===` at line 2 ?

Comment: Doesn't submit if all fields are blank - submits if 1 field has text and the others are blank or if they all have text and vice versa

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the jquery api you are using?

Comment: @Andrew , i don't know jQuery very well, maybe there is a better way, but try this one : `if(($('#name').val() > 0) && ($('#user').val() > 0) ....) alert('submitted') else alert('blank!')` **BETTER WAY = Jorge's answer**

Answer (score 3):

You cant do a .val on an array. It should be

```
function submitform(){
   var warning = false;
   $('#name, #email, #user, #address, #phone').each(function() {
      $(this).val().length === 0){
         warning = true;
         return;
      }
   });
   if(warning) {
      $(this).addClass('warning');
   } else {
      alert("form submitted");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to check each one of them with the `each` function in jquery, or a `for` loop.

```
$('#name, #email, #user, #address, #phone').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length === 0){
        $(this).addClass('warning');
    } else {
     alert("form submitted");
   }
});
```

Here's the same example with a for

```
var formElements = $('#name, #foo');

for (i = 0 ; i < formElements.length ; i++)
{
    if ( $(formElements[i]).val().length === 0 )
       $(this).addClass('warning');
    else {
       alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

```
function formSubmit() {
    var pass = true;
    jQuery.each( jQuery('#form :input'), function( key, value ) {
       if(!this.value && jQuery(this).attr('class :contains("required")')) {
         if (jQuery(this).siblings('.error').length === 0 && jQuery(this).type != 'submit') {
            jQuery(this).after('<label class="error"><span class="form-required">*</span> Required</label>');
         }
         pass = false;
       } else {
        jQuery(this).siblings('.error').remove();
      }
    });
    if (pass === true) {
        document.getElementById('form').submit();
    }
}
```